# How to check if multiple values inside database exists in yii

Tags: php, database, yii

I am having troubles inside my action controller. I need to check if (data1 and data2) doesnt exists in the database. If it exist, I want to render a page. If not, render to another page. I dont think that I can use isset in here? can somebody point me to the correct direction? thanks!

Comment: data1 and data2 are attributes of the model?

Comment: yes sir. @DanielVaquero

Answer (score 2):

You can **check** if the table has a **attribute** with this code:

```
$existData1 = $model->hasAttribute('data1'); // Return boolean true if the attribute exist in the model table.
```